# Grabbing an Element from a variable with node-set in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to get a value from a variable within an XSLT document. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">

  <Composition xmlns="Playlist">
    <xsl:variable name="source_var">
        <Source identifier="0">Inside Source</Source>
    </xsl:variable>

    <Video>
        <xsl:value-of select="ms:node-set($source_var)/Source"/>
    </Video>
    </Composition>

</xsl:template>
```

Its not working. The output is this:

`<Composition xmlns="Playlist">
  <Video></Video>
</Composition>`

When it should be this:

`<Composition xmlns="Playlist">
  <Video>Inside Source</Video>
</Composition>`

When I remove the namespace `xmlns="Playlist"` from the `<Composition>` tag it works. So I am think it has to do with the name space, but I have to keep the namespace in.

I feel the `ms:node-set($source_var)/Source` is looking in the wrong namespace, but I dont know how to fix the probelem.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<xsl:variable name="source_var">
    <Source identifier="0">Inside Source</Source>
</xsl:variable>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="source_var" xmlns="">
    <Source identifier="0">Inside Source</Source>
</xsl:variable>
```

if you can, or to

```
<xsl:variable name="source_var">
    <Source xmlns="" identifier="0">Inside Source</Source>
</xsl:variable>
```

If you can't change the namespace of the element then you need to use a prefix in your path e.g. you need

```
<xsl:value-of select="ms:node-set($source_var)/ns1:Source" xmlns:ns1="Playlist"/>
```

Of course instead of putting the declaration on the `value-of` you can also put it on the `xsl:stylesheet`.